# Forcing appliation to open in the desktop that they have started

Tags: 14.04, unity, desktop-environments

I don't know if this is a bug or feature? I have 4 desktops in my Ubuntu. I start an application in say Desktop #2 and then I immediately switch to Desktop #1 to continue working on another application. But the application which was started in Desktop #2 will appear in Desktop #1.

Is there a way to avoid this?